# Съезжает третий блок <div>, как поставить их в ряд?

Tags: css, html

```
.leftbody {
    width:225px;
    height:350px;
    border:1px solid black;
    float:left;
}
.centerbody {
    width:450px;
    height:350px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left:225px;
}
.rightbody  {
    width:225px;
    height:350px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-left:675px;
}
```

При написании этой строки третий блок(rightbody), он съезжает вниз

https://pp.vk.me/c637716/v637716995/f270/AUPGsgfh9F4.jpg

Comment: Ты забыл прибавить border к margin-left, из за него съезжает

Comment: Он мне нужен в одной строчке, при написании border, он встаёт вниз

Comment: Добавьте html код в вопрос.

Comment: Проблему решил, всем спасибо, я не записал в .centrbody float:left;

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас есть более современный метод позиционирования блоков на странице, это **flexbox**. Снизу я приведу пример и ссылку на jsfiddle и статью об флексбоксах. Вначале покажется запутаным, но за час-другой разберетесь. Если же решили все таки флоатами, тогда ладно. Главное что вам надо сделать, это убедиться что вы действительно знаете ширину каждого из блоков, учитывая все отступы. Для более точного и удобного контроля за этим, я всегда пишу

```
div {
  border-box: box-sizing;
}
```

Теперь, если с флоатами, и статической шириной страницы, вам надо сделать так:

```
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.mainDiv {
  overflow: hidden;
  width:900px;//допустим, такая ширина всей страницы/ сумма всех блоков
}
.mainDiv > div{
  float: left;//чтобы не писать для каждого отдельно 
}

.leftbody {
  width:225px;
  height:350px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.centerbody {
  width:450px;
  height:350px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.rightbody  {
  width:225px;
  height:350px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Ну и пример с флексбоксами:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainDiv">
    <div class="leftbody"></div>
    <div class="centerbody"></div>
    <div class="rightbody"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  border-box: box-sizing;
}
.mainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.mainDiv > div {
  width: 50%;
}
.leftbody {
    height:350px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.centerbody {
    height:350px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.rightbody  {
    height:350px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9arL2cj4/

Забыл статью добавить, [**FLEXBOX**](http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/)